# Notepad++ regex delete comma at the end of the line if last two characters are capital letters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to delete comma at the end of the line if there is at least 2 capital letters before it.

For example:
SOME TEXT,

What I want to achieve:
SOME TEXT

I have tried using `[A-Z]{2},$` but it also marks those without capitals.

Also I'm not sure how to delete that comma there.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Also check `match case`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot to checked `Match Case`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=[A-Z]{2}),$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[A-Z]{2})   # positive lookbehind, make sure we have 2 capital letter before
,               # comma
$               # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: omg, you're right! How could I miss that... Now I have to find out how to delete that coma.

Comment: @Maredha: Leave `Replace with` empty and click on `Replace All`

Comment: That wont help, because those 2 characters need to be there, I just need comma to disappear and only in case where 2 characters before it are capital.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D I was searching for some answers for hours now, everything I tried didn't worked. Thank you again.